# how to check whether user input is double value or not?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7

if user give other than double value like string/alphanumeric/alphabets/some illegal values (ex:1;2), it should not accept as double and give an error message.
how to write it in c++.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You Usually want to do the conversion with `strtod`. That will set a pointer to the end of the input that it could convert to a double. After it returns, you can check that to see whether it converted none, part, of all of the input, and react accordingly.